# Is there a easy way to copy a "slider" from a template you bought and use in another wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Is there a easy way to copy a "slider" from a template you bought and use in another wordpress site?

Like this template,
http://www.missbee.se/eliteRehab/

Or does anyone know a "slider" plugin who looks similar to the example (with big text field)?

Comment: This question is very broad.  The simple answer is of course "yes" it is possible to move code around.

Comment: Is there a easy way to take out salt from Indian Curry you bought and use in another baingan bharta ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, it only depends on coding skills.

Also for slider in WP i suggest to use http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ or http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding but for both of them you to know a little bit wordpress templating, html, jquery and css of course. Same conditions also for moving a slider from a pro theme to a custom new one.

Good luck! :)